# What firmware updates should I be tracking?

Tags: firmware

Seems like everything has possible firmware updates these days. Not just PC BIOS, but network cards, routers, printers, monitors, etc.

The other day I heard about a firmware update for a mouse. I wouldn't have guessed to look for that, and the manufacturer of the mouse doesn't have a way to get my attention. I wish Windows Update (or equivalent on other platforms) would do all this for me, but it sure doesn't.

Maybe you have a list of things you look for firmware on?

Comment: Lexus just did a Firmware update on my car, so add car to your list!

Comment: I have the motto: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it"

If there are no issues or security reasons to flash firmware, I recommend you don't. There is always the risk the device will become a brick after flashing.

My 2 cents

Comment: Moab said it well.  Its just not worth potentially ruining your device unless there are specific advantages to the new firmware that you will notice and appreciate.  Don't upgrade just to be up to date.

Comment: Still it is interesting to know which types of devices routinely have firmware updates.

Answer (score 4):

While Moab's thoughts can sometimes be correct you might not know it is an issue until it is broken or someone else takes advantage of your older firmware. Sometimes running new firmwares can get you but the same goes for running older ones and you can't trust the changelogs, they might resolve something they didn't want you knowing about.

Here is what I can come up with:
home phones, cell phones, printers, network switches and routers, UPS, CD-Roms, DVR's

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the list:
video card BIOS/UEFI updates
TV cards
I've heard of firmware updates for HDDs and SSDs.
keyboards (fancy ones to be honest)
fax modems (hardware fancy ones)
calculators  (usually graphing ones)
Intel's processors (these usually go over Windows Update or BIOS update, because processor's microcode can't be flashed so it needs to be updated at every system start.)

Can't think of anything else at the moment.