# Apps for multi-device firmware updating of my PC

Tags: windows, updates, hardware-failure, firmware

According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/159178/what-firmware-updates-should-I-be-tracking), are there some free (freeware) applications that can help me easily update whole PC's hardware's firmware? App that can find and install new versions of firmware for every single device that's in my PC, like new BIOS for motherboard, graphic card, network card or firmware for hard drive .etc?

Or even paid apps, I'd just like to know.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no easy, magic-bullet app for that; as least not that I'm aware of.

If there is, I would STRONGLY recommend against using it. :)

Firmware is *very* device and revision specific.  The way to load a firmware varies wildly between devices, manufacturers and sometime between firmware releases.

If there is trouble writing the firmware you can easily end up with a "bricked" (dead/useless) device.

Check out this SU question: [What is firmware and what happens when I update it?](https://superuser.com/questions/132428/what-is-firmware-and-what-happens-when-i-update-it)

I think it has some points which may help you see why this would be a bad idea (an app that does them all).

Comment: I know what problems users can encounter while trying to update their firmware. And i know that there are specific types of firmware. Such app that i was looking for should consider specific versions of firmware and update only to newer versions of them - but that's not a topic for suggesting.

The main questions, which still hasn't been answered is "there's an app for updateing firmware of every single hardware device in pc?".

Comment: The answer is "No, there isn't one (at least not that I'm aware of)". :)  The rest of the info was to inform you as to why one (probably) doesn't, and shouldn't, exist.